# textView automatically resizes my text, how do i stop it?

Tags: ios, textview

I have a custom UITableViewCell, which expands when the user taps on it. within the cell I have a UITextField, that expands with the cell when it is tapped. However when the text within the textView is longer than the cell (before expansion) it shrinks all of the text to fit that size, does anyone know how to stop this?
Thanks

Comment: Without code ?? it so complicated for us :(

Comment: `UITextField` , `UILabel` or `UITextView` ? Confused by your question

Comment: UITextVew, @Raptor. I think i have fixed the problem but I'm not sure if its a good way. i've basically coded the font and size of the textview, instead of on the storyboard. is this a correct way of solving it?

Comment: Depends on how you code it. I didn't see any code so far.